# Quality Center - Can I get the items from dropdown box in QC?

Tags: c#, hp-quality-center

I am using Quality Center's OTA API in C# and I need to get the items from the dropdowns in QC to a SQL database. Some lists weren't long so I did them manually but the [BG_PROJECT] list has a lot of items so I really don't want to do it manually. How would this be done?

Answer (score 0):

On TDConnection object you have Customization property. 
On it you have Customization Listening.

CustomizationLIsts allows access to all the lists defined in the project.

You can see exact api in documentation.

Answer (score 0):

Dropdown list values are stored in the Customization.Lists object.
I don't know C# but I'd do it like this in VBA:

```
QCC As TDConnection
myList As CustomizationList
I As Integer
```

Initialise QCC object and connect to domain and project then:

```
Set myList = QCC.Customization.Lists.List("NameOfList")
For I = 1 To myList.RootNode.Children.Count
    MsgBox(myList.RootNode.Children.Item(I).Name)
Next I
```

(Btw, I wouldn't really use MsgBox() to display each value of the list, I used it here to demonstrate my general approach).